# How to access a webpage with body display:none using Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I see the following HTML code when I import it from website throught selenium. The ids I want to access are hidden inside the body and I am not able to access them using Selenium Python.

```
</head>
    <!--[if IE 9]>
    <body style="display:none" class="ie9">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
    <body style="display:none">
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

This is the code I see in the website through inspect option.

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form login col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" data-stage="DataStore1">
        <fieldset class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
<label class="sr-only separator" for="idToken1">
    <span>Benutzername</span>
</label>
<input type="text" id="idToken1" name="callback_0" value="" data-validator="required" required="" data-validator-event="keyup" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Benutzername" autofocus="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
<label for="idToken2" class="aria-label sr-only separator">
    <span>Passwort</span>
</label>
<input type="password" id="idToken2" name="callback_1" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Passwort" value="" data-validator="required" required="" data-validator-event="keyup">
                </div>
                        <div class="remember-forgot clearfix">
                            <div class="checkbox pull-left">
                                <label for="remember"><input type="checkbox" name="loginRemember" id="remember"> Remember my username</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                <div class="form-group">
<input id="loginButton_0" name="callback_2" type="submit" role="button" index="0" value="Log in" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-uppercase btn-primary">
                </div>
            ch license between the licensee and ForgeRock AS.
           </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I am using Chrome webdriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\WebDriver\bin\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://app.int.eu.acdc.fdc.swarm.audi/goldenalgo#dario/data-distribution')
a = driver.find_element_by_id("idToken1")
a.send_keys(username)
print(w.value_of_css_property("display"))
print(driver.page_source)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id('idToken2').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id('loginButton_0').click()
driver.close()
```

`driver.find_element_by_id("idToken1")` this doesn't work and returns the error "unable to find element with css selector error in selenium".

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using id `idToken1`, and the HTML that you have shared does not contain this id, can you share the relevant HTML ? also check for iframe

Comment: I have added the idToken1 details, can you take a look now, thanks:)

Comment: Do you see any iframe ? What code did you tried and was there any error ?

Comment: I didn't see any iframe. I updated the post to include the code